# Graphs of functions

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions, inverse-function

Is there a rule or way that will help us graph $f(\frac{1}{x})$ if $f(x)$ graph is known? Or is the only way plotting values? I thought of this question when we learned that the graph $f^{-1}(x)$ is the mirror image of $f(x)$ across $y=x$.

Comment: I'm sure you've already realized this, but $f(\frac{1}{x})$  would have zeros where $f(x)$ had asymptotes and have asymptotes where $f(x)$ had zeros. Essentially, the $y$ coordinates would be reciprocals of the original. The only common points wold be wherever $y=1$ or $y=-1$.

Comment: Yeah, I did. That sort of helps but I still won't be able to get the shape of the entire graph with that right?

Comment: With the remainder, let's start with positive $y$ values of $f(x)$. Look at points on the graph where $0<y<1$. Find where $y=0.5$. For your new graph, this will be $2$. Then, do the same where $y=0.25$, which will give your new graph a value of $4$. Then, find $y$ values of the original that are $2$ and $4$, and graph them as $0.5$ and $0.25$ for your new graph. Repeat this process with negative $y$ values.

Comment: This should give you a much more accurate graph approximation with a lot more points of reference. Keep doing this until you reach the level of accuracy you want (incorporate eights, thirds, fifths, or whatever you want).

Comment: I usually imagine a crunching of x values larger than 1 into the space of x values less than 1 and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question, but the answer is not so satisfying.  In the situation of an inverse function, $y = f^{-1}(x)$ if and only if $x = f(y)$.  So, naturally, you're switching the $x$ and $y$ when passing from the graph of $f$ to the graph of $f^{-1}$.  As you point out, this is a *reflection* across the line $y=x$, which is a particularly nice type of *linear transformation*.  In fact, it's an *isometry* (a.k.a. *congruence*, a.k.a. *rigid motion*) of the plane, which means that it preserves distances and angles (and the shape and size of objects).

Unfortunately, the passage from $y = f(x)$ to $y = g(x) = f(\frac{1}{x})$ is not such a well-behaved transformation.  What you have to do is understand
$$
x \,\longleftrightarrow\, \frac{1}{x}.
$$
For simplicity, let's restrict our attention to $x>0$.  A point $(x, y)$ is on the graph of $y = f(x)$ if and only if the point $(\frac{1}{x}, y)$ is on the graph of $y = g(x)$.  Replacing a number by its reciprocal distorts distances:  for instance, the distance between $1$ and $2$ is the same as the distance between $10$ and $11$, but for their reciprocals, the distance between $1$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ is much greater than the distance between $\frac{1}{10}$ and $\frac{1}{11}$.  The infinite ray $[1, \infty)$ is flipped over and contracted to cover the interval $(0, 1]$ by taking reciprocals.

The behavior of $f(x)$ as $x \to 0$ determines the behavior of $g(x)$ as $x \to \infty$ and vice versa, but the shape of the curve changes.